# Git pulling from another remote repository

Tags: git, repository, fetch, git-remote

I have 3 directories in my computer: 'repo1', 'repo2', 'repo3'. They were working normally so I was being able to pull, commit and push on them. Today, I entered on 'repo1' and tryed to pull from master. Git gave me an error: 'refusing to merge unrelated histories', so I pulled using the command `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`. Everything went fine and the 'repo1' have been updated. Then, I went to 'repo2' which is the current repository I'm working on and tryed to make a pull request. Git did it, but instead pulling objects from 'repo2', it pulled from 'repo1'. I ran the `git remote -v` command and it show the following remotes:

```
origin  https://github.com/user_name/repo1.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user_name/repo1.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/user_name/repo2.git (push)
```

I tryed to change the URL, but git only changed the last origin. Also, if I ran `git remote -v` on 'repo3', it show the same result as above. Now, all my remote are pulling from 'repo1'. I don't know what I've done. If someone can help me repair this, I appreciate. Thanks and sorry my bad english.